# Flatpak: Install a Flatpak app without installing some of its dependencies

Tags: dependencies, latex, flatpak, texstudio

How do I install a Flatpak app without installing one of its dependencies which is not really required?
For instance, if you wanted to install the TexStudio App ([org.texstudio.TeXstudio](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.texstudio.TeXstudio)), Flatpak would pull in the TeX Live SDK (org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.texlive) as a dependency, which is about 4.8 GB in size.
The [TexStudio](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.texstudio.TeXstudio) App page at flathub mentions the following:

> Requires either TeX Live being installed on the system from your distribution's repositories or the TeX Live Flatpak which you can install by running 'flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.texlive//21.08'

But it does not explain how you can install it without installing the Flatpak's Tex Live dependency.

Since I already have TeX Live installed in my system, I do not want to install the Flatpak's version of TeX Live, is there a way to install an app using Flatpak without installing it's "dependencies"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install a flatpak package without its dependencies, you can provide `--no-related` flag.

For example, if you want to install `texstudio` without installing `texlive`, you can try this:

```bash
flatpak install org.texstudio.TeXstudio --no-related
```

Answer (score -1):

With the option `--no-deps`? See `flatpak install --help`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/413040)